# How to create Commerce Repeat Order link a view?

Tags: e-commerce, drupal-8, drupal-views

After 3 days of searching how to create `Repeat Order` link in a view, I'm not able to find a way.
I tried searching every where. Drupal stack exchange, drupal support, drupal commerce support in slack, but no luck.

**My issue :** 
I have a view that lists all the orders. The last column in the view is a custom text column which I created by using replacement patterns. Every link in the `Actions` column are either replacement patterns, or anchor tag with `href` defined for them. The `Repeat` button right now is also an anchor tag but does nothing. I want to create a repeat button that repeats a particular order.

[image]

In the description of "Commerce Repeat Order" in drupal.org, it says :

`Link can be created as l('Repeat Order','commerce-repeat-order/%') where % is order id which needs to be passed dynamically to repeat that order.`

I'm not able to figure out a way to create link as field in view.

Answer (score 0):

My solution:

1- Add new "Global: Custom text" field in view "User Orders" and do these options - pic. "global-tex.png"
[image]
2- If your order's type (admin/commerce/config/order-types) is physical, change "default" to "physical" in CommerceRepeatOrder Controller (modules/contrib/commerce_repeat_order/src/Controller/):

```
// Loading existing cart.
$cart = $this->cartProvider->getCart('default', $this->order->getStore());
if (empty($cart)) {
    // Creating new cart is there is none.
    $cart = $this->cartProvider->createCart('default', $this->order->getStore());
```

That's all.